# Can't access contents of a Security-Scoped directory URL

Tags: swift, macos, directory, security-scoped-bookmarks

I have the following code to enumerate through a directory.
The URL to the directory is passed in as a parameter to the function.

The `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` returns `true` at the start of the function, however when I start to enumerate it returns `false` for all the following files and subdirectories inside the original folder selected by the user.

This is the code for the function.

```
func readDirectory(file: URL){
    
    let localFileManager = FileManager()
    let resourceKeys = Set<URLResourceKey>([.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey])
    let directoryEnumerator = localFileManager.enumerator(
        at: file,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: Array(resourceKeys),
        options: .skipsHiddenFiles
    )!

    
    for case let fileURL as URL in directoryEnumerator {
        guard let resourceValues = try? fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: resourceKeys),
            let isDirectory = resourceValues.isDirectory,
            let name = resourceValues.name else {
            continue
        } 
    }
}
```

From the above code, the `file` parameter passed does return true for access. However, in the `directoryEnumerator` loop, the `fileURL` doesn't have access.

**Is there a reason that I am losing access to the subdirectories and files inside the original directory that it says I do have access to?**

Comment: Unrelated: but `Array(resourceKeys)` doesn't make much sense, given that you explicitly made `resourceKeys` a `Set`. You can just use `let resourceKeys: [URLResourceKey] = [.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey]`, and pass that array directly to `enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` and `resourceValues(forKeys:)`.

Comment: Have you found an answer to it? I am in a similar situation now